# Installing NuGet package from outside of Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dll, nuget, nuget-package

I'm working on a project wich will create boilerplates for new websites,
And based on what you select in the interface/GUI it will install certain modules to the new site.

Therefore I want to use NuGet "outside" of visual studio to add this Modules and the **references** to the project/solution file.

I have no problem installing packages to a certain path, it is just the references that I need to add to the solution.

I wonder if anyone have done something similar and can give some guidance?

Regards,
Halle

Comment: Isn't editing the project file enough to accomplish what you need?

Comment: I'm actually working on doing that, I just wanted to know if i can achive this in another way than editing XML by code. Thanks for the answer

Comment: I take it you create plain Visual studio projects. In that case a simple reference in the project file is probably the easiest approach. If you're creating VS Project Templates, there is [a good guide](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/packages-in-visual-studio-templates) on using Nuget packages.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I realize the easiest way might be to add a reference to the solution file via code. I will take a look on the guide you refered to aswell, cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the NuGet packages just contain one or more assemblies that are added to your project references then adding the reference with custom code is probably the simplest way.

If the NuGet packages include content files, such as scripts, then you will need to add those too.

If the NuGet packages rely on PowerShell scripts then you could probably use a custom build of [SharpDevelop](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2011/06/12/InstallingNuGetPackagesOutsideVisualStudio.aspx). This is a heavyweight solution since it requires most of SharpDevelop to do the work.

There is also "nuget update" which should update to the latest versions of the packages, but it will not install them into a project from scratch.